# Field involving multiple rows from another table

Tags: sql, database, field

I have created/am creating 3 tables: **Slaves**, **Citizens** and **Incidents**.

How should I go about **Incident** involving multiple **Citizens** and **Slaves**? 
Now I'm thinking about making two fields in **Incidents** containing list of CitizenID's and SlaveID's (SlaveID1, SlaveID2...,SlaveIDn), but it seems plain dumb.

Comment: You have many to namy relationships. You can add two tables incidentCitizens and incidentSlaves. What is relationship of citizen and slave?

Comment: @Salvador you should really review the answers given below and show us some green ^ ^.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri The Citizens can have multiple slaves, but the citizen row doesn't contain information about that, only the Slave row indicates the Citizen who own the slave (this sounds horrid) :D

Comment: Thank you for the answers @TimBiegelsen, timus2001 and evictednoise ! , now back to the desk  ^__^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your idea doesn't sound dumb at all.  You can design your `Incidents` table like this:

```
+------------+-----------+---------+
| IncidentID | CitizenID | SlaveID |
+------------+-----------+---------+
|     1      |     A     |    A    |      <-- incident #1 involved 2 citizens and 1 slave
|     1      |     B     |    A    |
|     2      |     A     |    A    |      <-- incident #2 involved 2 citizens and 2 slaves
|     2      |     B     |    A    |
|     2      |     A     |    B    |
|     2      |     A     |    B    |
+------------+-----------+---------+
```

Now when you query for a certain incident ID you can obtain a list of all citizens and slaves involved in the incident.  This is a many-to-many relationship in your database schema.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it by making 2 bridge table along with one master table

```
Master table
_______________
Incidents

Bridge tables
___________
incident_slave(pk of incidents table , slave information field(s) or pk of slave table)
incident_citizen(pk of incidents table , citizen information field(s) or pk of citizen table)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a many-to-many relationship.

Basicly you could get away with a table of kind:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[incidents](
    citizen_id*
    ,slave_id*
)
```

The * mark means column is a part of primary key. This ensures there is only one relationship between citizen John and slave Patrick.